# How to find an element with a particular attribute and attribute value in directive template?- ng-conf 2015 example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the talk [creating content container components with web components and Angular](https://youtu.be/AbunztfV5vU?list=PLOxyk-LNhApINGi_P52OPfFrN0xMNh4L8&t=811) (specifically linked to the time where it is relevant to this question) ng-conf 2015 they talk about directive components creating and matching multiple insertion points. (creating behavior that matches web component insertion implementations). Good thorough 20 min talk, but they seem to leave it hanging slightly. For example,

```
// this being the html page
<my-site-container>
  <div t-to="menu">
    this displays in the menu/nav of the directive component.
  </div>
  <div t-to="body">
    this displays in the body/main of the directive component.
  </div>
</my-site-container>

// directive template

`<div id="site-container>
   <nav t-id="menu"></nav>
   <main t-id="body"></main>
 </div>"`
```

which needs custom code in the link function. (transclusion using just ng-transclude does not allow 'matching' of insertion points. See video for more.) **The questions are to their link function code in the DDO:**

```
return {
    transclude: true,
    template: ...,
    link: function(scope, elem, ctrl, transclude) {
            transclude(function(clone) {
              angular.forEach(clone, function(cloneEl)
                var tId = cloneEl.attributes["t-to"].value;
                var target = elem.find('[t-id="' + tId + '"]');
                target.append(cloneEl);
          });
  }
};
```

This did not work completely for me. Here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/l43NA50kNq8ZAAjuNbCN?p=preview).
**Question 1**. What is best way to filter out the elements with a t-to attribute?

the `var tId = cloneEl.attributes["t-to"].value;` **is undefined** when you have traditional markup structure meaning

```
// the forEach supplies empty-like node, <div..., empty-like node, <div...
<my-directive>
  <div t-to="menu">I render in the menu.</div>
  <div t-to="body">I render in the body.</div>
</my-directive>
```

// this forEach supplies correct and only the divs needed 
    I render in the menu.I render in the body.
   // so seems like traditional html structure when iterated will add the space in as empty text nodes.

I used if `(cloneEl.attributes) {var tId = ...}` in the plunk and that seemed to work

**Question 2**: What is best way to get an element in the directive template that has a certain name and attribute value?

`var target = elem.find('[t-id="' + tId + '"]');`
This code does not seem to make sense that it would work and well it is not for me. (**note:** elem is equivalent to the template or `temp` as they seem to have it in their code example.)

the `find` method how are they using it? They seem to be lookinf for the element by attribute name and value. I looked around for the `[]` syntax and couldn't find any reference to that. Angular limits the find to tag name. And they make no mention of jQuery but jQuery does not seem to have that feature either anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import jquery in your index before angular. After that, find() should work.